# How do I access a value on an [String: Any] Dictionary in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently, I have a dictionary with values on it, some of them are Objects, the values in the dictionary are as follows

```
["otherUserId": id,
"otherUser": {
    email = "zak@test.co.uk";
    name = zakmint;
    profileImageURL = "url";
 },
"lastMessage": {
    fromId = id;
    hasReadMessage = 0;
    text = What;
    timestamp = 1635800286;
    toId = id;
    type = TEXT;
},
"timeStamp": 1635800286]
```

How do I access the value of hasReadMessage, I am currently grabbing the dictionary like this then trying to access the value on top of it. But it has the type Any and Im not sure how to access the value without causing a compilation error.

```
                if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot {
                    guard let dictionary = childSnapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
                    print(dictionary)
                    let lastMessage = dictionary["lastMessage"]
                
                    let value = lastMessage.hasReadMessage
```

Comment: `lastMessage as? [String: Any]`. You have already cast `childSnapshot.value` into a dictionary, just do the same thing again.

Comment: You continue to cast as you did in the guard statement either as part of that guard statement or separate `if let …`. Another approach is to use a custom type.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez I get the same error "Value of type '[String : Any]?' has no member 'hasReadMessage'"

Comment: `let lastMessage = dictionary["lastMessage"] as? [String: Any]` --> `let value = lastMessage?["hasReadMessage"] as? Int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot treat a dictionary as a struct. The keys are **not** properties whose value can be accessed by dot notation.

You have to use key subscription and conditionally downcast each intermediate value to its proper type

```
guard let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot, 
      let dictionary = childSnapshot.value as? [String:Any],
      let lastMessage = dictionary["lastMessage"] as? [String:Any],
      let hasReadMessage = lastMessage["hasReadMessage"] as? Bool else { return }

print(hasReadMessage)
```